Use DirectX 11 & HLSL in SDL
I saw Lazy Foo using OpenGL & GLSL in SDL, but I want to use DirectX 11 & HLSL in SDL.
Is there a way to do this, and how?

This old post but might help others.
After you initialize and create window with SDL successfully, get the HWND from SDL_SysWMinfo as shown below,
SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &wmInfo);
HWND hwnd = wmInfo.info.win.window;

After this you can proceed normally and on how you would create and initialize a D3D11 device and swap chain. When you fill in the DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC you can set the OutputWindow field to the HWND obtained above.
swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;

Below is a sample code that will create D3D11 device, swap chain and clears the background to a color.
//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL_syswm.h>

#include<dxgi.h>
#include<d3d11.h>
#include<d3dcompiler.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11")
#pragma comment(lib, "D3DCompiler")

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    //D3D11 Stuff.....
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL  featureLevelsRequested = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL  featureLevelsSupported;

    ID3D11Device* pD3D11Dev = NULL;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* pD3D11DevContext = NULL;
    IDXGISwapChain *pSwapChain = NULL;
    ID3D11Texture2D *pRenderTargetResource = NULL;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView *pBackBuffer = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        

        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (window == NULL)
        {
            printf("Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        }
        else
        {

            // Get Window HWND
            SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
            SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);
            SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &wmInfo);
            HWND hwnd = wmInfo.info.win.window;

        
            //Swap Chain Desc
            DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc = {};
            swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
            swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
            swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
            swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
            swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
            swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
            swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
            swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;
            swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
            swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
            swapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;

            //Create device and swap chain
            HRESULT d3dHR = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
                NULL,
                D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                NULL,
                D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG,
                &featureLevelsRequested,
                1,
                D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                &swapChainDesc,
                &pSwapChain,
                &pD3D11Dev,
                &featureLevelsSupported,
                &pD3D11DevContext
            );

            if (d3dHR != S_OK) {
                return 0;
            }

            // Create ID3D11Texture2D resource as a buffer to draw stuff on
            pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pRenderTargetResource);

            if (pRenderTargetResource != NULL) {
                pD3D11Dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pRenderTargetResource, NULL, &pBackBuffer);
                pRenderTargetResource->Release();
                pD3D11DevContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &pBackBuffer, NULL);
            }

            //Viewport setup
            D3D11_VIEWPORT viewPort = {};
            viewPort.TopLeftX = 0;
            viewPort.TopLeftY = 0;
            viewPort.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
            viewPort.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

            pD3D11DevContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewPort);

            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

            //Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

            //Hack to get window to stay up
            SDL_Event e; 
            bool quit = false; 
            
            while (quit == false) {

                //D3D Render stuff
                FLOAT backgroundColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
                pD3D11DevContext->ClearRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, backgroundColor);

                pSwapChain->Present(1, 0); // Flip/Swap the back and front buffer 
                
                
                while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) { 
                    if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                        quit = true;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    //D3D Cleanup
    pSwapChain->Release();
    pBackBuffer->Release();
    pD3D11Dev->Release();
    pD3D11DevContext->Release();

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}


I'm not sure if neccesary manage manually DirectX 11 initialization: there is a SDL_render_d3d11.c file within the SDL sources, so probably if you simply start a renderer of that type all the DirectX 11 stuff is made inside SDL2 internally?
